# Boostrap affix underneath the fold

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently facing a weird problem which I could not solve in the last 2 hours, that's why I hope someone here is able to help me.

I am trying the get a sidebar navigation sticky (with bootstrap affix). If I do it above the fold -> it works smoothly. If I try to do it underneath the browser visible area it does simple not work.

Here is the fiddle I try to solve: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qKFqg/63/

```
  $('#winner').affix({
      offset: {
        top: function () {
          return (this.top = $('.comparison-table').outerHeight(true))
        }
      }
    });
```

---

```
<table class="comparison-table">
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#winner">
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>

    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>

    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div id="winner" class="affix" title="Testsieger">
      asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa 
asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the one which is working: 
http://jsfiddle.net/qKFqg/64/

```
    <table class="comparison-table">
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="rowTitle">Modell</th>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
    <td>ASDF</td>
  </tr>

</table>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#winner">
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>

    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>

    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
    <p>asasa</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div id="winner" class="affix" title="Testsieger">
      asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa 
asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa asasa     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the affix plugin works is that as you scroll, it figures out when you've hit your offset. At that point it adds a class "affix" to your element. In your CSS you would define that that means. Normally something like this:

```
.affix {
   top: 0;
}
```

That will make it so that when your element is about to go off the top of the screen, it will get stuck at 0. If you set an element to position:fixed without specifying an actual position for it, it will just stick in its natural location.

Here your fiddle with that added: http://jsfiddle.net/jbbugvrz/

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!